# MongoDb c# official driver bulk update

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

How can i rewrite the following old code via the new C# MongoDb driver which using `IMongoCollection` interface :

```
var bulk = dbCollection.InitializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
foreach (var profile in profiles)
{
   bulk.Find(Query.EQ("_id",profile.ID)).Upsert().Update(Update.Set("isDeleted", true));  
}

bulk.Execute();
```

How to create `Update` operation with `Builder` mechanism is clear for me, but how to perform update bulk operation ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MongoDB.Driver has `UpdateManyAsync`

```
var filter = Builders<Profile>.Filter.In(x => x.Id, profiles.Select(x => x.Id));
var update = Builders<Profile>.Update.Set(x => x.IsDeleted, true);
await collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update);
```

Comment: I'm glad this answer cover op necesities, but it doesn't answer the original question. Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687470/c-sharp-mongodb-driver-2-0-how-to-upsert-in-a-bulk-operation/35688613#35688613

Answer (score 0):

on new Version MongoDB.Driver can be set Flag

```
var query = Query<Profile>.In(p => p.ID, profiles.Select(x => x.Id));
var update = Update<Profile>.Set(p => p.IsDeleted, true);
Collection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);
```