# C# mongodb driver 2.0 - How to upsert in a bulk operation?

Tags: c#, mongodb, batch-processing, mongodb-.net-driver, bulk

I migrated from 1.9 to 2.2 and [reading the documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/quick_tour/#bulk-writes) I was surprised to discover that is not possible to upsert during a bulk operation anymore, since operations don't allow options.

```
bulkOps.Add(new UpdateOneModel<BsonDocument>(filter, update));
collection.BulkWrite(bulkOps);
```

Should be

```
options.isUpsert = true;
bulkOps.Add(new UpdateOneModel<BsonDocument>(filter, update, options));
collection.BulkWrite(bulkOps);
```

Is this work in progress, intended, or I'm missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Set the [`IsUpsert`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateOneModel_1_IsUpsert.htm) property of the `UpdateOneModel` to true to turn the update into an upsert.

```
var bulkOps = new List<WriteModel<BsonDocument>>();
// Create and add one or more write models to list
var upsertOne = new UpdateOneModel<BsonDocument>(filter, update) { IsUpsert = true };
bulkOps.Add(upsertOne);
// Write all changes as a batch
collection.BulkWrite(bulkOps);
```

Comment: This should be added to documentation. Thank you!!

Comment: what is bulkOps? How do I get one?

Comment: @gyozokudor bulkOps is `List<WriteModel<T>>`

Comment: What should I put in `filter`and `update` variables?

Comment: When your Id is a string, this does not work.

Answer (score 36):

given mongo collection

```
IMongoCollection<T> collection
```

and enumerable of records to insert where T has Id field.

```
IEnumerable<T> records
```

this snippet will do a bulk upsert (the filter condition may be changed according to the situation):

```
var bulkOps = new List<WriteModel<T>>();
foreach (var record in records)
{
    var upsertOne = new ReplaceOneModel<T>(
        Builders<T>.Filter.Where(x => x.Id == record.Id),
        record)
    { IsUpsert = true };
    bulkOps.Add(upsertOne);
}
collection.BulkWrite(bulkOps);
```

Comment: I like this approach but is it true that each "record" in "records" must contain an _Id value?  The source of my records does not include the _Id field.  So I need to locate single records using an alternate unique key, e.g. ukey. When I used x.ukey == record.ukey the update failed because the record._Id field is all zeros.  Is there a good way to do this in one upsert or do I have to fetch the target records so I can set the _Id column before doing the upsert?

Comment: I hesitated to use after i saw Replace. So used UpdateOneModel it was too slow. Just came again and checked it booom ! It's so fast.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method based on @Aviko response

```
public static BulkWriteResult<T> BulkUpsert<T>(this IMongoCollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> records)
    {
        string keyname = "_id";

        #region Get Primary Key Name 
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            foreach (object attr in attrs)
            {
                BsonIdAttribute authAttr = attr as BsonIdAttribute;
                if (authAttr != null)
                {
                    keyname = prop.Name;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        var bulkOps = new List<WriteModel<T>>();


        foreach (var entry in records)
        {
            var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(keyname, entry.GetType().GetProperty(keyname).GetValue(entry, null));

            var upsertOne = new ReplaceOneModel<T>(filter, entry){ IsUpsert = true };

            bulkOps.Add(upsertOne);
        }

        return collection.BulkWrite(bulkOps);

    }
```